# Opencart error - carousel.tpl

Tags: themes, opencart, carousel

Hey i buy a theme for opencart. Pav Dress responsive theme
i upload it and now when i load page it tell to me this

> Notice: Undefined property: Loader::$language in
>   /home/ot011700/_sub/testik/catalog/view/theme/pav_dress_store/template/module/carousel.tpl
>   on line 1
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in
>   /home/ot011700/_sub/testik/catalog/view/theme/pav_dress_store/template/module/carousel.tpl
>   on line 1

Here is carousel.tpl file

```
<?php $id = rand(1,10); $span =  floor(12/$limit); $this->language->load('module/themecontrol') ;?>
<div class="box category">
  <h3 class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $this->language->get('text_shopby_brands');?></span></h3>

  <div class="box-content clearfix">
    <?php foreach ($banners as $i=> $banner) {  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" title="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
    </a>
   <?php } ?>
 </div>
 </div>  
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#carousel<?php echo $module; ?> ul').jcarousel({
    vertical: false,
    visible: <?php echo $limit; ?>,
    scroll: <?php echo $scroll; ?>
});
//--></script>
```

Can you help me resolve it ? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using opencart 2.x, this theme is invalid for your version

Comment: How its possible. ? on their page is written it supported by opencart 2.0 :/

Comment: they might have another version, but that one is not 2.x compatible